# Nginx wrong redirection multiple virtual host SSL and not

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I am using nginx in a docker container as a webserver for multiple application containers. One of those application is expecting an https connection and the other not.

In the examples to come, I use standard names but in my case, app2 name starts with a "d" and app1SSL starts with a "g". I point this out in case alphabetical order can explain this behavior.

For the first app (app1SSL) using SSL, I would like that nginx redirect:

- http://www.app1SSL.com
- http://app1SSL.com
- https://www.app1SSL.com

to https://app1SSL.com

For the second app (app2) not using SSL, I would like that nginx redirect:

- http://www.app2.com

to http://app2.com

Here, I know, I will have errors concerning security. This is work in progress, I have no domain name, I use my local hosts file to map app2.com to the IP address of my server (see file below)

With the confs I have nginx serve for http://app1SSL.com the content of http://app2.com (with no redirection).
It works fine for everything else. Redirections for other app1SSL addresses and app2 addresses works fine.

See confs files below:

/etc/hosts:

```
#
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

161.35.xxx.xxx www.app2.com
161.35.xxx.xxx app2.com
```

nginx app1SSL.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.app1SSL.com app1SSL.com;

    ssl_certificate ... # works fine
    ssl_certificate_key ... # works fine

    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    set $upstream http://app1SSL:80; # Forward to another container

    location / {
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}
```

nginx app2.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.com www.app2.com;

    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    set $upstream http://app2:3000; # Forward to another container

    location / {
        proxy_pass $upstream;
    }
}
```

Now if I add to app2.conf, it works.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

What cause this bad behavior and is my work around the best way to solve my issue ?

Comment: Can you rephrase in the end of the question, what exactly is the issue? Not sure if its me only, but I am not able to get what the exact query is

Comment: I've try, hope it's clearer